# Am I using LiveData properly in this code? (works)

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm new to Android development, and am trying to use a good pattern for accessing my data from a web service using ViewModel, Retrofit, LiveData. Looking for feedback on this pattern.

I went through a few iterations and online guides, and came up with this

From the Activity:

```
LiveData<TicklerResponse> ticklerLiveData = 
ticklerViewModel.search(ticklerSearchObject);
    ticklerLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<TicklerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable TicklerResponse ticklerResponse) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: ticklerResponse size = " + ticklerResponse.getContent().size());
        }
    });
```

The ViewModel

```
public LiveData<TicklerResponse> search(TicklerSearchObject ticklerSearchObject) {
    TicklerRepository ticklerRepository = TicklerRepository.getInstance();
    String header = OscarOAuthContainer.getInstance()
            .generateAuthorizationHeader(Verb.POST,"/tickler/search?startIndex=0&limit=1000");
    MutableLiveData<TicklerResponse> liveData = new MutableLiveData<TicklerResponse>();
    ticklerRepository.search(header,liveData, ticklerSearchObject);
    return liveData;
}
```

The Repository

```
public void search(final String authHeader, final MutableLiveData<TicklerResponse> ticklerLiveData, TicklerSearchObject ticklerSearchObj) {
    Log.d(TAG, "search: called");
    Call<TicklerResponse> call = api.search(authHeader,0,1000,ticklerSearchObj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TicklerResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TicklerResponse> call, Response<TicklerResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: successful response for getProvider");
                TicklerResponse result = response.body();
                ticklerLiveData.setValue(result);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: NOT SUCCESSFUL");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TicklerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

It seems to work, but I'm concerned if I'm using the LiveData structure correctly in how it's being instantiated/passed around.

Comment: The answer depends on how proper you want to be.. One simple change you could make is to modify `Repository.search()` method to instantiate a new `MutableLiveData` instead of getting it as a parameter. Then, `Repository.search()` method can return the `MutableLiveData` instance as a `LiveData`.

Comment: Also, currently The ViewModel is not really serving as a view model as in MVVM. Right now it looks more like a helper class. For example, you could just move `search()` method into the Activity or even make it a static method, your app won't really be affected.

Comment: thanks, I made some improvements, and it looks much better now